# Algorithm to get combinations one by one without storing them into memory

Tags: java, algorithm, combinatorics

I have an array which is N ints long and I have an input int X. I need to populate whole array with combination of ints whose sum gives X. I need to find all possible combinations, the order matters and the array has fixed length (const N). For example if X=3 and N=4 I need to get this:

```
[3, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 1, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 1, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 2, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 2, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 3, 0, 0]
[0, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 2, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 3, 0]
[0, 0, 2, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 3]
```

Moreover I don't want to store all possible combinations in memory but I need to get these values one by one. For example when I called a method NEXT last time I got [0, 2, 0, 1]. When I call it again I need to get next combination [0, 1, 2, 0]. When I call it again I need to get [0, 1, 1, 1] and so on.
Is there an alorithm that can do that? Thank you

Comment: To avoid memory issues, you probably want to store a series of chained iterators that only keep what index they have reached so far

Comment: "I have an array[N] of ints" and "all combinations of values in the array". The problem sounds badly formulated. I.e. if you have an array like {0,1,2,3}, the there are 2^4 possible combinations (in the combinatorial sense of the definition) and only the following combinations match e.g. 3

{1,2},
{0,1,2},
{3},
{0,3}

Comment: @juvian Not a duplicate, it's a different problem.

Comment: @Vojtech its exactly the same except in your case you don´t want to use more than N numbers, but solutions proposed can be easily modified to add that restriction

Comment: I updated the description, hope the difference is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified generation of compositions in colex order to fit your ordering.
 Working Delphi code, I hope it is understandable (`Dec(P)` is equal to `P--`)

```
  function next(): Boolean;
  var
    nonzero, last: integer;
  begin
    last := C[n - 1];
    if last = x then  // the last composition
      Exit(False);

    C[n - 1] := 0;
    nonzero := n - 2;
    while C[nonzero] = 0 do //find the last nonzero element
       Dec(nonzero);

    Dec(C[nonzero]);
    C[nonzero + 1] := 1 + last;
    Exit(True);
   end;

begin
  n := 4;
  x := 3;
  SetLength(C, n);
  C[0] := x;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(ArrToStr(C));
  while next() do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(ArrToStr(C));
```

output

```
3 0 0 0 
2 1 0 0 
2 0 1 0 
2 0 0 1 
1 2 0 0 
1 1 1 0 
1 1 0 1 
1 0 2 0 
1 0 1 1 
1 0 0 2 
0 3 0 0 
0 2 1 0 
0 2 0 1 
0 1 2 0 
0 1 1 1 
0 1 0 2 
0 0 3 0 
0 0 2 1 
0 0 1 2 
0 0 0 3
```

Comment: Excellent, it so easy and it does exactly what I need. Thank you!